# How to get string resource name by its value

Tags: android, resources

I want to get a string resource name or ID by passing its value.
Example :

```
    <string name="stringName">stringValue</string>
```

I want to pass the stringValue and get the stringName or ID (id value)

Based on ID i will do some calculation to get another ID of another String resource

Comment: Axarydax : it's not the same ... I want to pass the value not tha name . I cannot use getResources().getIdentifier

Comment: ???!!!!! Axarydax, Luksprog, Kazekage Gaara, Simon, Andro Selva : Please read the question carefully before closing....it's not duplicated

Comment: Voted for reopening. By the way for what in the world do you need this?

Comment: did u find a solution ? I am stuck for same

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's possible and I think the IDs can change without warning if the R class gets newly generated. You could of course try some reflection magic on this class, but I would recommend against it.

Comment: That's right kolja.. but i can play on the resource name even if the id is changed

Comment: I don't think you can find the resource's id using it's value.

Comment: Actually . it's possible by reading the contents of String.xml as a text file .. But it's not the right way. I'm wondering if there are some functions to do that.

Comment: Maybe you would be better off using an XML file or some other means to store your Strings. I still haven't understood what exactly you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, and can think of 2 possible workarounds:

- load all the strings and their names into a table, and look in the
  table.
- Or cycle through my complete list of names, getting the string resource
  for each one, and comparing it to my known string resource.

I am implementing the 2nd one, as my list of string resources is not very big, and I don't have to do this operation very often.  Once the name is known, it's possible to get the Resource Id via:

```
//Get resource id from name
    var resourceId = (int) typeof (MyApp_droid.Resource.String).GetField(MyStringName).GetValue(null);
```

(code is C# because I'm working in Xamarin).